# pyenv unable to find docker-compose

Tags: python, macos, docker, pyenv

I think I may have screwed up my local py environment on my Mac.

I've installed pyenv and a couple of python versions:

```
$ pyenv global
2.7.17
3.7.7
```

It seems to have decided to wrap itself around docker-compose...

```
$ which docker-compose
/Users/wintermute/.pyenv/shims/docker-compose
```

I've got a local env I want to run python3 in:

```
$ cd mysite
$ pyenv version
3.7.7 (set by /Users/wintermute/mysite/.python-version)
```

But now I can't run docker-compose in it:

```
$ docker-compose up
pyenv: docker-compose: command not found

The `docker-compose' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.5

Note: See 'pyenv help global' for tips on allowing both
  python2 and python3 to be found.
```

And worse, it won't even run in the version it says to use:

```
$ pyenv local 2.7.5
$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
(and a load of debug traceback messages)
```

I've tried `pyenv rehash`. I think I originally had python installed via homebrew. What can I do to unscrew my local environment? Why can't it find docker-compose? What have I *done*??

Answer (score 3):

I was using the command `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` in my `~/.zshrc` to enable pyenv.  You need to check your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` for a similar command.  This modifies the PATH and put the shims first which creates the issue. (You can run `pyenv init -` to see what happens). Remove the `eval` and manually added the shims to the path AFTER the existing PATH.

```
export PATH="${PATH}:"$(pyenv root)/shims
```

I haven't thoroughly tested it, but it fixes the docker-compose issue.
Check out [Pyenv Advanced Configuration](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#advanced-configuration) for more info.